# Phrases vs sentences

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

Why do some well known sentences or sayings like '**The customer is always right**' fall into the category of phrase or catchphrase?

What is the distinction between a sentence that we call a phrase, as in my example and the ones we don't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Phrase* has several meanings; one meaning is common and non-technical, the other is technical grammar.

The common meaning is basically just 'a familiar string of words'. So all the adages and proverbs and sayings and whatnots are "phrases" in this sense. Not a lot of meaning, really -- a phrase can be **any** string of words.

As for why some strings catch on and some don't, that's a good question. If anybody ever finds a good answer, they can become rich very fast, because that would be predicting the future, and nobody has ever been able to do that.

The technical grammatical meaning, however, is that a phrase is a ***Constituent*** of an utterance -- typically a constituent of a sentence -- that has its own structure and integrity. English sentences typically consist of a Noun Phrase called the Subject, followed by a Verb Phrase that's sometimes called the predicate, which may contain other Noun Phrases like a Direct Object; either phrase may contain other phrases, like Preposition Phrases, consisting of a preposition with an object Noun Phrase.

As you can see, there are lots of kinds of phrases; the most important thing about them is that they have functions, and boundaries, and that they are often marked by special words (like complementizers, articles, prepositions, conjunctions, quantifiers, articles, etc. -- the "nuts and bolts" words that mark English grammar).